# Issue triggering in-app messages containing deep links

Tags: java, android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm trying to trigger Firebase in-app messages with native Android deep links but the message doesn't display. The campaign name does display in my logcat so I believe it skips it

```
I/FIAM.Headless: Already impressed Android On Boarding Message 2 Test FV ? : false
```

The setup is there are 4 FIAM campaigns with a deep link button to trigger the next campaign message. The deep links opens the onNewIntent function, then an event is triggered. Another FIAM campaign waits for the event to trigger, then is supposed to display the message.

This how I am triggering the event:

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("viewed_onboarding_message2");
```

Firebase support told me messages only show on the activity that triggered the event, so deep links might be causing the issue. Some things I tried were adding intent flags, changing the launch mode to singleTask, and using logEvent instead of triggerEvent. The goal of this project is to create multiple on-boarding messages the first time users open the app.

Comment: Can you share the dependencies you are using in Project?  You have to add FIAM display SDK to show the messages.